# Having both files in a directory that matches a controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've run into quite a large problem.

I have a SoftwareController which has a Shapeshifter action, so that my URL is http://flamefusion.net/software/shapeshifter.

Now, if I make a folder called Software\Shapeshifter on the FTP of the root webserver folder, MVC crashes when trying to access the controller, even if I'm not accessing a specific file.

So my question is this: How can I put up a file at http://flamefusion.net/software/shapeshifter/downloads/shapeshifter.exe without ruining the MVC functionality as well? I tried doing some URL rewriting using the `Global.asax` file, but without luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried setting routes.RouteExistingFiles = true and then ignoring routes with specific extensions of files that you access directly? so you global.asax would look something like:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("*.exe");
    routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
    //rest of route maping code goes here
}
```